# Docker image for java application made with Ant build

Tags: docker, ant

Is it possible to create a docker image for java application that is built with ANT ?

Comment: Yes, this is definitely possible.  What does your current Dockerfile look like?  What problem are you running into?

Comment: I don't really know how to create it because I haven't seen any example of it on the Internet.